# temp table from alias relation does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get total row number from tempTable2, but the error says
"relation "temptable2" does not exist"

```
select
  (
    select count(*) from tempTable2
    where (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (maxdailylog - mindailylog))/3600)>4.5
  ) as totalHadir,
  (
    select count(*) from tempTable2
    where (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (maxdailylog - mindailylog))/3600)<4.5
  ) as absenTidakKomplit
from
  (
    select LogHari, mindailylog, maxdailylog, count(LogHari) as jumlahLog from(
       select waktuabsen::date as LogHari,
         min(waktuabsen) over (partition by userid, waktuabsen::date) as mindailylog,
         max(waktuabsen) over (partition by userid, waktuabsen::date) as maxdailylog,
         dense_rank() over (order by waktuabsen::date) as grouplistno
       from sdm.tabsen
       where userid=866 and waktuabsen >= '2020-03-01T00:00:00' and waktuabsen < '2020-03-31T00:00:00'
      ) as tempTable
      group by grouplistno, LogHari, mindailylog, maxdailylog
  ) as tempTable2
```

Comment: use small Case in table and column names or put all camel case names in double quotes ""

Comment: Hi @AkhileshMishra I have changed to small letters. but still now work out.
what can i do to fix it?

Comment: can you post you table schema and some sample data and desired output to help you better

Comment: I have found the solution.
I used "with" as temp table.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary tables can be accessed from the same session from which they are created. For any other session they won't be available. Try running the query in the same window or same session where you have created temporary table